# @Typed annotation stops Groovy code compiling

Tags: groovy, groovy++

Why does this Groovy code...

```
def mt(){
  def i= 0
  def c= {i++}
}
```

...compile, but this Groovy code...

```
@Typed def mt(){
  def i= 0
  def c= {i++}
}
```

...not compile with error...

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:  
C:\Users\gavin\Documents\Personal\Groovy\otherRun.groovy: 5: 
Cannot modify final field otherRun$mt$1.i @ line 5, column 11.  
 def c= {i++}
         ^
```

Comment: Just realized I can use a reference  
`@Typed def mt(){  
  def i= new Reference(0)  
  def c= {i.set(i.get() + 1)}  
}`  
though of course it's more verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around the restriction via the @Field annotation, like so:

```
@Typed def mt(){
    @Field def i = 0
    def c = {i++}
}

assert mt().call() == 0
assert mt().call() == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[This issue](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/issues/detail?id=383) posted to the google code tracker states:

> This is by design.

And links to a [message on the user group](http://groups.google.com/group/groovyplusplus/browse_thread/thread/d41af6e721b9bace), which states:

> Yes, this is one of most significant differences with standard Groovy.
>   In Groovy++ shared closure variables are always final.

I cannot see how you could rewrite that code you have in a groovypp friendly way, so I guess you would either need to refactor the code to do it another way, or else not declare it as @Typed

***Edit***: I guess you could encapsulate the behaviour in a class, and return a method handle to a member function